# Grab a specific property bag using ECMA script

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, property

I am trying to grab a key/value pair from a specific property bag but can't find any documentation or example code on how to grab a property bag. Currently I can only seem to grab allProperties. Here is my code:

```
    <CommandUIHandler
          Command="FCS.Intake.Tab.Reports.TL"
          CommandAction="javascript:
          function getWebProperty() {

        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();
        this.props =  web.get_allProperties();

        ctx.load(web);

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, gotProperty), Function.createDelegate(this, failedGettingProperty));
    }

    function gotProperty() {
      window.location.href = this.props.get_item('PropertyKey1');       
    }

    function failedGettingProperty() {
        alert('failed');
    }
  getWebProperty();"
        />
```

This doesn't work because the key/value pair is located in a property bag as opposed to a site property.

Does anyone know how to grab a specific property bag using ECMA script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find a way to grab a specific property bag, but using the information from Aaron's post (loading this.props), one can grab a property bag as an xml string, parse that xml and grab the specific value they are looking for. Here is how I did it:

```
function getWebProperty(propKey, propBagName) {          
  var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();
  this.props =  web.get_allProperties();
  this.propKey = propKey;
  this.propBagName = propBagName;
  ctx.load(web);
  ctx.load(this.props);
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, gotProperty), Function.createDelegate(this, failedGettingProperty));
}

function gotProperty() {
      var myPropBag = this.props;
      // Grab specific property bag as xml
      var myPropBagXML = myPropBag.get_fieldValues()[this.propBagName];        
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(myPropBagXML, 'text/xml');
      xmlDoc.async = 'false';
      var propValue = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(this.propKey)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      alert(propValue);                
}

function failedGettingProperty() {
    alert('failed');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try loading this.props

```
function getWebProperty() {

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();
    this.props =  web.get_allProperties();

    ctx.load(web);
    ctx.load(this.props); //need to load the properties explicitly
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, gotProperty), Function.createDelegate(this, failedGettingProperty));
}
```

Then in your success function, you need to access the property bag's values by running it through get_fieldValues() and then an indexer for the key to the property.

```
function gotProperty() {
    var myPropBag = this.props;
    alert(myPropBag.get_fieldValues()["allowdesigner"]); //returns the value of the key allowdesigner
}
```

Firefox's firebug will allow you to do

```
console.log(myPropBag.get_fieldValues());
```

which will print out all the property bag keys to the console window.

Thanks,
-@SharePointAP

Comment: This is great, thanks. Is there any documentation on SP2010 JavaScript client object model? I couldn't find much.

Comment: Also I know which property bag I want to grab, I still don't know how to grab it. I have tried:
        var myPropBag = this.props;
        var myPropBag1 = myPropBag.get_fieldValues()['propertyBag'];
        alert(myPropBag1.get_fieldValues()['myPropBagKey']);

With no luck.

Comment: The documentation on the Javascript client object model isn't as extensive as the server object model. But you could start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538253.aspx

Comment: There's just one property bag there so you can simply do alert(myPropBag.get_fieldValues()['myPropBagKey']); Just make sure you're loading this.props - ctx.load(this.props) before executing your success function. This will ensure the property bag is loaded.

Comment: I have multiple property bags, and when I call one of them from myPropBag.get_fieldValues()['propbagIwant'], it returns xml. Will I have to parse that xml to get the specific value that I want? Or is there a way to grab that specific property bag, then grab the specific value of that property bag?

Comment: I only know of a few property bags: Farm, WebApp, SiteCollection, Web and List. If there are more property bags than that, then that's outside my expertise, sorry. But in the code above, we're getting the web's allProperties. It should just be a hashtable of key/val pairs. If the key returns xml, that **may** be the value and something you have to parse out.

Comment: You can create your own property bag, which is what I did in this case. When I call on it from allProperties, it returns xml that contains keys (element names) and values (element values). I can just parse the xml and get the value that way. I don't even know if you can return a specific property bag using the JavaScript COM, I haven't found any code or documentation how to do so yet.

Comment: Wow, I didnt know that. I'll have to try that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since here is no answer covering the actual question - "Grab a **specific** property bag using ECMA script" here's some code to do exactly that:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebProperties, "sp.js");
var webProperties;
function getWebProperties() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    webProperties = clientContext.get_web().get_allProperties();
    //get a single property
    clientContext.load(webProperties, 'FollowLinkEnabled');
    // get multiple properties
    // clientContext.load(webProperties, 'FollowLinkEnabled');
    // clientContext.load(webProperties, '__PublishingFeatureActivated');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.getWebPropertiesSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function getWebPropertiesSucceeded() {
    var allProps = webProperties.get_fieldValues();
    for (var prop in allProps) {
        console.info(prop + ' : ' + allProps[prop]);
    }
}

function onQueryFailed(args, sender) {
    debugger;
    //handle errors here
}
```

Here's the result when requesting the 2 mentioned properties:

[image]

*Why should i request single values instead of getting the whole package?*

Simply to reduce network traffic and increase the performance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can grab a specific property as [mentioned here](http://www.thesharepointbar.com/?p=219).

The trick is to load, not the web but the object returns from "web.get_allProperties".

Then, you just need to call `.get_item('name_of_the_prop_you_want_to_retrieve')`

Hope it helps