# How to get SPSite aka SPWeb property bags using ClientContext?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, jquery, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grab a specific property bag using ECMA script](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37198/grab-a-specific-property-bag-using-ecma-script)

I would appreciate if some paste a sample code to get the property bags values using ClientContext?

Comment: Could you please write some more text explaining what this is really, about, so we can use it to help eachother better in the future. That would be awesome :-)

Comment: it was a duplicated post and already been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was recent discussion here regarding the very same topic. Refer to this thread:
[Grab a specific property bag using ECMA script](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37198/grab-a-specific-property-bag-using-ecma-script)

Answer (score 3):

Just to complete the answer provided in the link. If your property bag value is a plain text, not a serialized xml settings (as in the other question), you can use **get_item** function directly:

```
function getWebPropertyValue(key) {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
    var web = ctx.get_web()
    var props = web.get_allProperties()
    ctx.load(props)
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        var value = props.get_item(key);
        alert(value);
    }, function() {alert("failed");})
}

//test
getWebPropertyValue("vti_approvallevels");
```

Comment: +1 Thank you, it has already been answered by the person above :)